# Securing IIS sub folders and files

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I have an ASP.NET Application running on IIS windows 2008R2 Server, everything is working ok however users are able to access the direct files in subfolders. What i am looking for is a way to prevent the users from accessing anything outside of the default document.

I have tried removing the security to the sub folders and files but this leads to an issue that the application cannot gain access to the files in sub folders.

The application pool is running under application pool identity and the folders have the permission only for the application pool identity.

I have also tried many other variations but i cannot seem to remove the access to these files without causing the application not to work.

Comment: What kinds of files are you talking about? IIS wouldn't serve up DLLs, config files, raw pages, controls, views, etc. - and anything else should be able to be moved outside of the website or virtual directory and onto the regular filesystem, without disrupting your application.

Comment: does your app require authentication?

Comment: We are using windows authentication so only domain users can access however we do not want them to access anything. The files that we have are *.js *.png *.html they are spread across various sub filders within the virtual directory

Comment: Javascript, HTML, and images are supposed to be accessed by the client. That's how the web works. You can't just turn that off and still have a working web application, unless they're not used at all, in which case you can remove them entirely.

Comment: I do agree about that however i am just looking for a way that they cannot just call the file directly to get the code.